# Improve JPA update() performance improvement with partitioned tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, database-partitioning

With hibernate, I have a JPA entity with an `Id` field of `UUID` type, a `date` field of `Instant` type, and some other fields including collection with One to Many relations.
To illustrate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sport_car")
public class SportCar implements Serializable {

  @Id
  UUID id;

  Instant date;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  List<Sponsor> sponsors;

  ...
}
```

For performance, I decided to partition the `sport_car` table by `date`, one for each day, since a lot of `SportCar` are added each day.

To improve the `SportCarJpaRepository.update()` I was thinking on setting a composite key/id to `SportCar` including `date`, but the problem is on the `sponsors` attribute.
The performance improvement should be noticeable since most updates are done on latest day instances.
To make the One to Many reference I need to add a new column in the table where class `Sponsor` is mapped, because JPA assumes that you need all the id columns in the `sport_card` table to make the unique reference, when is not really necessary, because the `id` field is unique.

To illustrate

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SportCarId.class)
public class SportCar implements Serializable {

  @Id
  UUID id;

  @Id
  Instant date;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "sport_car_id")
  List<Sponsor> sponsors;
  
  ...
}

public class SportCarId implements Serializable {
  UUID id;
  Instant date;
}
```

This won't work because the `SportCar.date` field is not referenced in the `@OneToMany` relations on the `SportCar.sponsors`.
My question is, does Hibernate/JPA provides a way to optimize the `update()` taking advantage of the partitioning?

Comment: I am not an expert in DB partitioning/optimizations but doesn't joining `Sponsor`s to `SportsCar` on `id` alone defeat the whole purpose of having a partitioned `(date, id)` index (which I presume is the optimization you're talking about)?

Comment: (assuming of course you'll want such a join at some point and not just `SELECT * FROM Sponsor WHERE sport_car_id = ?`)

Comment: Yes, it does. But  `Sponsor` is lazy fetched, and it will be partitioned also.